# Excel macro create csv files from workbook sheets windows popup issue

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an issue in converting an excel to csv file. My use case is to write a macro to convert each workbook sheet into csv file and zip them up to a single file.
  so my code goes like this 
      'OriginalWorkbook.Activate
    'For the number of Sheets convert each into its own CSV file

```
For Counter = SHCOUNT + 1 To Sheets.Count

     'Export as CSV to the root folder
     Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Counter)
     wks.Copy 'to a new workbook
     Set newWks = ActiveSheet
     With newWks
        fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(newWks.Name, _
        fileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (fileSaveName)
        .SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ZipNAme = newWks.Name
        If fileSaveName <> False Then
            'newWks.Delete
            'MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
        End If

        .Parent.Close Savechanges:=False
    End With

    ''Add the created CSV file to the ZIP file
    Set oapp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oapp.Namespace(FolderName).CopyHere fileSaveName

Next Counter
```

But Now i am facing an issue with this code ,  I have some 20 sheets in the excel  and for each sheet , windows saveas popup is coming up and i have click 20 times save to get this entire thing done.

i am very new to the coding in VB . Can anyone help me out with this ?
I have to go ahead without any save as popup as i am giving the file name beforehand.

Thanks,
B1

Comment: You are getting a popup for each file because you are calling `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` inside the loop!

Comment: is there an alternate way ? or a solution  for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub exportcsv()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps, can't guarantee that it might work for you but it's an alternative to get things on the right path. I myself am also new to VBA  :)